# X,Y are independent RVs with known characteristic functions. Find P(X+Y=2).

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving, characteristic-functions

X,Y are independent random variables with the following characteristic functions:

$ \phi_X(\theta) = \frac{1}{4}e^{i\theta}+\frac{3}{4}e^{i2\theta} \\
  \phi_Y(\theta) = exp(e^{i\theta}-1)=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac{e^{i\theta k}}{k!})$

Find: P(X+Y = 2)

Taking the product of the characteristic functions (since the characteristic function of the convolution/sum of X + Y is the product of their char functions), we get:

$\phi_{X+Y}(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}e^{-1}\sum_{K=0}^\infty(\frac{e^{i\theta (k+1)}}{k!})+\frac{3}{4}e^{-1}\sum_{K=0}^\infty(\frac{e^{i\theta (k+2)}}{k!}) \\$

Somehow, my lecturer goes from this line directly to: $\\$
$\therefore P(X+Y=2)=\frac{1}{4}e^{-1}\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{3}{4}e^{-1}\frac{1}{0!}=e^{-1}          $

Could someone please explain how my lecturer has made that step above. I can't seem the work it out. I thought maybe he was using some property of the Poisson distribution, since Y is Poisson distributed with $\lambda=1$. But, I couldn't see how he did that when the (K+1) and (K+2) components were in the indices, for the characteristic function of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can read off the distributions. For $X$, it is $1$ with probability $1/4$ and $2$ with probability $3/4$.  Now $\Pr(X+Y=2)$ is an elementary calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure this explains how I get from one step to the other in the mathematic transcribed above..

Comment: Yeah.. It seems you're looking at an older version of the page. I fixed it about half an hour ago :)

Comment: Probably did not refresh when I returned.

Comment: If you have a distribution on the non-negative integers, you can write down the characteristic function in terms of powers of $e^{it}$. By uniqueness, if you are given a sum of such powers, you can read off the probabilities. So by combining the two series, you can read off probabilities.